# Build fails when AppsFlyer is used with ProGuard

Tags: android, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I'm following [this manual](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-Android) to integrate AppsFlyer into our Android app.

When I try to build the project with `minifyEnabled true` the following warnings appear in the build log:

> Warning: com.appsflyer.GcmInstanceIdListener: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService
>
> Warning: com.appsflyer.GcmInstanceIdListener: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID
>
> Warning: com.appsflyer.GcmInstanceIdListener: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService
>   Warning: com.appsflyer.GcmInstanceIdListener: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID
>   Warning: com.appsflyer.GcmInstanceIdListener: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID
>
> Warning: com.appsflyer.GcmInstanceIdListener: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService
>
> Warning: com.appsflyer.GcmInstanceIdListener: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService
>
> Warning: com.appsflyer.u: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService

And the build fails.

Here is relevant part of the app's module build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4+@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
}
```

Here is relevant part of ProGuard configuration:

```
-dontwarn com.android.installreferrer
```

Comment: Try this -dontwarn  com.appsflyer.GcmInstanceIdListener

Comment: AppsFlyer SDK uses optional linking with both Firebase and old GCM. so `-dontwarn com.appsflyer.**` will solve the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add the following as well:

```
-dontwarn com.appsflyer.**
```

https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-Android#11-known-issues